# Remove Item From Object SubList (LINQ)

Tags: c#, linq

I have an object that looks like this :

```
public class Consortium
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(EnumDescriptionConverter))]
    public SourceType Type { get; set; }       

    public List<UserLibrary> Branches { get; set; }
}
```

Each `Consortium` has a list of `UserLibrary`'s associated with it, and that class looks like this :

```
public class UserLibrary
{
    public string LibraryId { get; set; }

    public string RetailerId {get; set;}

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method which will allow the user to remove a library from one of their consortium (note: There may be many branches associated to the consortium).

However, I'm only being supplied a `LibraryId`, so I'm forced to traverse their list of `Consortium`, find which one contains the given id, then iterate over the branches and remove the one that matches the id.

Here is how I'm currently accomplishing this :

```
// Get the current list of consortiums
var user = _mediator.Send(new GetUserProfileCommand { UserProfileId = _principle.UserProfileId });
var userConsortia = user.SavedConsortia;

// the consortium to remove the library from
var branchToRemove = _libraryService.GetLibrary(id);
var consortRemove = new UserConsortium();

foreach (var userConsortium in userConsortia)
{    
    if (userConsortium.Branches.FirstOrDefault(c => string.Equals(c.LibraryId, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) != null)
    {
        consortRemove = userConsortium;
    }
}

// if the consortium id is null, something is f*
if (consortRemove.Id == null)
{
    return new JsonDotNetResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}

// first remove the consortia
userConsortia.Remove(consortRemove);

// remove the branch from the consortium
consortRemove.Branches.RemoveAll(ul => string.Equals(ul.LibraryId, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

// add it back in without the branch
userConsortia.Add(consortRemove);
```

**Question :**

Is there a LINQ expression I'm missing here that can help me consolidate this logic, or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a few approaches you can take depending on taste. The easiest way to simplify what you've got would be this:

```
var branchToRemove = _libraryService.GetLibrary(id);
// .Single() will throw an exception unless there is one and only one match.
var consortRemove = userConsortia.Single(
    c => c.Branches.Any(
        b => string.Equals(b.LibraryId, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
// remove the consortia
userConsortia.Remove(consortRemove);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like this? It looks to me from your code that you want to remove the targeted "removal branch" from all consortiums in you collection.

```
foreach (UserConsortium userConsortium in userConsortia)
{
    userConsortium.Branches.RemoveAll(c => string.Equals(c.LibraryId, id, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}
```